# hide HTML div when printing page

Tags: html, css, printing, xhtml, stylesheet

I have a XHTML-based page which contains admin information. The admin should be able to print the page, but I would like it to hide their information.

Is there a way to set a print area when printing a page, or is the only viable solution to open up a secondary page without the admin information when clicking on the "print" button?

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.dontprint
{ display: none; }
</style>

<div class="dontprint">I'm only visible on the screen</div>
```

Comment: But elelmnt dissappear completly also from common browser view. How to make it visible on site but when I want to print this make printer ignore it without redirecting to other site?

Answer (score 12):

You can set the CSS for that div to `display: none` using the following:

```
@media print {
    div.do-not-print {display: none;}
}
```

It'll display normally, but when you go to print, it'll use that CSS class.

Answer (score 5):

Add print.css to your page in which you hide all the elements that you don't want to be printed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

the media="print" attribute tells the browser to use specific css file.

In that file you can have

```
.admindetails{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure, You can add a diffrent stylesheet for printing, See below example

```
<link href="print.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

or in exiting stylesheet, you can add media query

```
@media print {
    .no-print {display: none;}
}
```

And add .no-print class where you do not want to print HTML element